# How to reliably detect dropped netlink requests or responses

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, netlink

I'm interested in using netlink for a straightforward application (reading cgroup stats at high frequency).

The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html) cautions that the protocol is not reliable, hinting that the application needs to be prepared to handle dropped packets:

> However, reliable transmissions from kernel to user are impossible in
>   any case.  The kernel can't send a netlink message if the socket buffer
>   is full: the message will be dropped and the kernel and the user-space
>   process will no longer have the same view of kernel state.  It
>   is up to the application to detect when this happens (via the `ENOBUFS`
>   error returned by `recvmsg(2)`) and resynchronize.

Since my requirements are simple, I'm fine with just destroying the socket and creating a new one whenever anything unexpected happens. But I can't find any documentation on what the expectations are on my program—the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvmsg) for `recvmsg(2)` doesn't even mention `ENOBUFS` for example.

What all do I need to worry about in order to make sure I can tell that a request from my application or a response from the kernel has been dropped, so that I can reset everything and start over? It's clear to me that I could do so whenever I receive an error from any of the syscalls involved, but for example what happens if my request is dropped on the way to the kernel? Will I just never receive a response? Do I need to build a timeout mechanism where I wait only so long for a response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following in [*Communicating between the kernel and user-space in Linux using Netlink sockets*](https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/laurent.lefevre/pdf/JS2010_Neira_Gasca_Lefevre.pdf) by Ayuso, Gasca, and Lefevre:

> If Netlink fails to deliver a message that goes from kernel to user-space, the `recvmsg()` function returns the *No buffer space available* (`ENOBUFS`) error. Thus, the user-space process knows that it is losing messages [...]
>
> On the other hand, buffer overruns cannot occur in communications from user to kernel-space since `sendmsg()` synchronously passes the Netlink message to the kernel subsystem. If blocking sockets are used, Netlink is completely reliable in communications from user to kernel-space since memory allocations would wait, so no memory exhaustion is possible.

Regarding acks, it looks like worrying about them is optional:

> `NLM_F_ACK`: the user-space application requested a confirmation message from
>   kernel-space to make sure that a given request was successfully performed. If this
>   flag is not set, the kernel-space reports the error synchronously via `sendmsg()` as `errno` value.

So it sounds like for my simplistic use case I can just use `sendmsg` and `recvmsg` naively, reacting to any error (except for `EINTR`) by starting the whole thing over, perhaps with backoff. My guess it that since I only get one response per request and the responses are tiny, I should never even see `ENOBUFS` as long as I have only one request in flight at at a time.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, we can see the dropped netlink packets in the `Drops` column of */proc/net/netlink*. For example:

```
# cat /proc/net/netlink
sk       Eth Pid    Groups   Rmem     Wmem     Dump     Locks     Drops     Inode
76f0e0ed 0   1966   00080551 0        0        0 2        0        36968
36a83ab1 0   1431   00000001 0        0        0 2        0        30297
d7d5db8e 0   563    00000440 0        0        0 2        0        19572
a10eb5c0 0   795    00000515 704      0        0 2        0        23584
c52bbce9 0   474    00000001 0        0        0 2        0        17511
3c5a89a5 0   989856248 00000001 0        0        0 2        0        31686
051108c1 0   0      00000000 0        0        0 2        0        25
ed401538 0   562    00000440 0        0        0 2        0        19576
38699987 0   469    00000557 0        0        0 2        0        19806
d7bbb203 0   728    00000113 0        0        0 2        0        22988
4d31126f 2   795    40000000 0        0        0 2        0        31092
febb9674 2   2100   00000001 0        0        0 2        0        37904
8c18eb5b 2   728    40000000 0        0        0 2        0        22989
922a7fcf 4   0      00000000 0        0        0 2        0        8681
16cfa740 7   0      00000000 0        0        0 2        0        7680
4e55a095 9   395    00000000 0        0        0 2        0        15142
0b2c5994 9   1      00000000 0        0        0 2        0        10840
94fe571b 9   0      00000000 0        0        0 2        0        7673
a7a1d82c 9   396    00000000 0        0        0 2        0        14484
b6a3f183 10  0      00000000 0        0        0 2        0        7517
1c2dc7e3 11  0      00000000 0        0        0 2        0        640
6dafb596 12  469    00000007 0        0        0 2        0        19810
2fe2c14c 12  3676872482 00000007 0        0        0 2        0        19811
3f245567 12  0      00000000 0        0        0 2        0        8682
0da2ddc4 12  3578344684 00000000 0        0        0 2        0        43683
f9720247 15  489    00000001 0        0        0 2        11       17781
e84b6d30 15  519    00000002 0        0        0 2        0        19071
c7d75154 15  1550   ffffffff 0        0        0 2        0        31970
02c1c3db 15  4070855316 00000001 0        0        0 2        0        10852
e0d7b09a 15  1      00000002 0        0        0 2        0        10821
78649432 15  0      00000000 0        0        0 2        0        30
8182eaf3 15  504    00000002 0        0        0 2        0        22047
40263df1 15  1858   ffffffff 0        0        0 2        0        34001
49283e31 16  0      00000000 0        0        0 2        0        696
```